# ApiExplorer: How to Change The Default for IgnoreApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

We have a couple of `ApiController` implementations and we do not want most operations to be included in the metadata of ApiExplorer.

By default, if you do not add `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` to your operation, it will be added so this means the default is false.

This probably due to `IgnoreApi` being a boolean and defaulting to `false` but how can I change this default to `true` without having to override `ApiExplorerSettings`?

This is a basic WebApi implementation without using MVC components.

I tried looking around for simple config based solutions or examples of `ApiExplorerSettings` usage but none have really worked out for me.

The closest to what I want is: [DotNetCore - is ApiExplorer supported, and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368750/dotnetcore-is-apiexplorer-supported-and-how-to-use-it); however, it focuses on MVC.

```cs
    // For example
    [RoutePrefix("api/test")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("helloworld")]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
        public string HelloWorld() {
            return "Hello world!";
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("goodbyeworld")]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
        public string HelloWorld() {
            return "Goodbye world!";
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("hiworld")]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
        public string HelloWorld() {
            return "Hi world!";
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("seeyaworld")]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
        public string HelloWorld() {
            return "See ya world!";
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to just use `ApiExplorerSettings` on operations which I want to use instead of marking the ones I do not want to use.

Comment: One option: create a constant.  Set the attribute value to that constant.

Comment: @Amy That could work but we wanted to use or reuse something that was already part of the .NET framework.

Comment: Constants are part of the language already....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are interested, I ended up overriding the ApiExplorer class to override the ShouldExploreAction and ShouldExploreController methods. I reversed the boolean logic there and it works as requested.

[Edited with example as this was requested]

You can do the following:

### Make a class that overrides from ApiExplorer

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using System.Web.Http.Routing;

namespace WebApi.Api
{
    public class CustomApiExplorer : ApiExplorer
    {
        public CustomApiExplorer(HttpConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the controller should be considered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="controllerVariableValue">The controller route parameter value.</param>
        /// <param name="controllerDescriptor">The associated <see cref="HttpControllerDescriptor">controller descriptor</see>.</param>
        /// <param name="route">The associated <see cref="IHttpRoute">route</see>.</param>
        /// <returns>True if the controller should be explored; otherwise, false.</returns>
        public override bool ShouldExploreController(string controllerVariableValue, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, IHttpRoute route)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerVariableValue) || controllerDescriptor == null || route == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }

            var setting = controllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            // Basically you check if there is a setting used and if ignore is set to true or false. You can also check if the routing is as one would expect but that is a different discussion. With this the ApiExplorer changes its logic by only registering API's that actively state IgnoreApi = false.
            if (setting != null && !setting.IgnoreApi)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

### Use custom class in WebApiConfig

In the WebApiConfig.cs file you can overide the IApiExplorer service instance by placing the following line in the Register(HttpConfiguration config) method.

```cs
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
    ...
    config.Services.Replace(typeof(IApiExplorer), new CustomApiExplorer(config));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you include an example?

Comment: @ChrisGonzales It shouldn't be that difficult to reproduce but I added an example anyway.

Comment: I could be doing something wrong here, but the `ApiExplorer` type used in your answer seems to no longer be inheritable (or at least not in ASP.NET 5+)

Comment: @thebugsdontwork I'm not entirely sure which version I was using at the time but I can only say that ApiExplorer is part of the System.Web.Http.Description namespace. Perhaps it has been deprecated or changed over time.

Answer (score 2):

you can the IDocumentFilter interface to achieve it:

```
    public class ApiDocFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            var pathsToRemove = swaggerDoc.Paths
                .Where(pathItem => !pathItem.Key.Contains("/api/"))
                .ToList();

            foreach (var item in pathsToRemove)
            {
                swaggerDoc.Paths.Remove(item.Key);
            }
        }
    }
```

in Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices use the filter:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "some API", Version = "v1"});
    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    c.DocumentFilter<ApiDocFilter>();//<-- use doc filter
});
```