# Get all registered routes in ASP.NET Core 1.1 application

Tags: asp.net-core

On an ASP.NET Core 1.1 application I need to get all registered routes so in a controller action I have:

```
public IActionResult GetAllRoutes() {          
  var routes = this.RouteData.DataTokens;
  return Ok(routes);
}
```

This seems to only return parameters of the current route. I also tried:

```
public IActionResult GetAllRoutes() {    
  var routes = RouteData.Routers.OfType<RouteCollection>();
  return Ok(routes);
}
```

This seems to only return the current route ...

Any idea how to get all registered routes in an ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435734/get-list-of-all-routes