# Get Swagger URL programmatically in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5, and Swagger. I know how to use Swagger, *and it works properly*.

Swagger is served on `foo:5001/swagger` - but I need to determine that URL programmatically at runtime.

How can I do that?

---

I already tried:

1. Getting it [by injecting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66086633/9971404) `IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource>` into some helper/controller class, but that shows me all routes EXCEPT swagger's.
2. Getting it while [setting up](https://github.com/kobake/AspNetCore.RouteAnalyzer/issues/28#issue-630104187) endpoint routing and inspecting `IEndpointRouteBuilder`, but once again it shows me all routes EXCEPT swagger's.

Comment: Probably it's not what you're looking for, but it might be easier to configure that swagger route from a value stored in IConfiguration, and then you could grab the same value in your other component too. ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to sources at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/SwaggerUIMiddleware.cs you can use an instance of class `SwaggerUIOptions`:

1. Register instance in DI container:

```
var options = new SwaggerUIOptions 
{
    RoutePrefix = "swagger"
};
options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "waiting_list v1");
services.AddSingleton(options);
```

2. Use configured instance:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<SwaggerUIOptions>());
```

3. Inject instance to any controller/class:

```
public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, SwaggerUIOptions swaggerOptions)
{
}
```

Property `RoutePrefix` contains swagger prefix (without leading '/')

This idea works only if options object passed to `UseSwaggerUI` method (available since version 6.0.0). If `UseSwaggerUI` invoked using callback (like a `UseSwaggerUI(a => { a.RoutePrefix = string.Empty; })`) it won't work.