# How to programmatically discover all API urls in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-5

I am writing a Windows service in ASP.NET Core 5 that hosts web service API's (i.e. controllers).

At the end of the startup sequence, I would like write to the log file a list of all web service API URL's that exist in the service.  Is there a way to programmatically find and list all valid web service API's?

Comment: By reflection. By scanning all classes whose inherit from `ControllerBase`, then their methods marked with an Http verb attribute, I'd say.

Comment: This Question is already answered [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435734/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-routes-in-asp-net-core)