# aspnet core get configured route templates

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

is it possibile retrive the endpoint templates configured  on the  `Configure` method in the `StartUp.cs` ?

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {           
    endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<TranslationTransformer>("{tenant}/{slug}");
    endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<TranslationTransformer>("{tenant}/{typology}/{slug}/{id}");
            });
```

I try to export the template section for passing   passing it to an `/routing` api

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435734/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-routes-in-asp-net-core/66086633#66086633

Comment: @abdusco thanks, it's work fine