# How to get the summary of the controller and action

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am implementing [IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apiexplorer.iapidescriptiongroupcollectionprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to get the API description.

I have implemented in this way

```cs
private readonly IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider _apiExplorer;

public RouteController(
    IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider apiExplorer)
{
    _apiExplorer = apiExplorer;
}

[HttpGet("all")]
public IActionResult GetRoute()
{
    var paths = GetApiDescriptionsFor("v1");

    return Ok();
}
```

I want to bind all the details of the controller to an ApiRouteDocument custom model with a description of the action too. But the interface I have implemented doesn't give a summary of the `action`, and the `controller`. Is there any built-in interface to extract the summary from the actions?

I wanted to avoid the Reflection.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/contact")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Contact")]
public class ContactController : ControllerBase
{

    /// <summary>  
    /// Get by Name Contact  
    /// </summary> 
    [HttpGet("getbyname/{name}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByName(string name)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

```
public class ApiRouteDocument
{
    //controllername tag
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerDescription { get; set; }
    public IList<RoutePath> Paths;
}
public class RoutePath
{
    //get
    public string Method { get; set; }

    //operationid
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //summary
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //path
    public string Path { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435734/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-routes-in-asp-net-core/66086633#66086633

Comment: I didn't see the summary and descriptions as I have decorated in the action and controller name.

Comment: You can get it from `ControllerTypeInfo`

Comment: Oh you mean the comments? That's a bit difficult. They're not included in the assembly. You have no way of getting it at runtime. You can export the docs then read the XML, though.

Comment: not the comments but the description about action and controller for example if it is a create actions, I want to add `Create a new contact.`. Or it could be like decorating action and controller with attributes.

Comment: You can set it with an attribute `[Summary("Create a new contact")]`, which you can read with reflection

Comment: Yeah something like that but without the reflection?

Comment: Reflection isn't a bad thing as long as you're not doing it too often / on a hot path. Microsoft's own `ApiExplorer` abstractions work via reflection too. The whole framework is built upon the dynamism that's only possible with reflection

Comment: The link to the solution you have posted is a nice example, how to add the attribute description on that? any example you can provide?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this code after the middleware pipeline has been established (and `app.UseEndpoints()` has been executed), so it should run inside a controller, or an endpoint, for example.

Because documentation comments aren't included in the assembly, you need to use attributes to annotate your classes & actions. You have the option to use the ones provided by Microsoft, such as `[DisplayName]`, `[Description]`, etc. under `System.ComponentModel.Primitives` namespace.

Or you can create your own attribute:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
internal class SummaryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Summary { get; }

    public SummaryAttribute(string summary)
    {
        Summary = summary;
    }
}
```

Then inject `IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource>` in a controller, which will give you the list of discovered endpoints.

You can get reflected runtime type info from `ControllerActionDescriptor`, then extract the attributes you've added to controllers & actions.

```cs
[Description("Provides info")]
[Route("info")]
public class ThingsController : ControllerBase
{
    private IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> _endpointDataSources;

    public ThingsController(IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpointDataSources)
    {
        _endpointDataSources = endpointDataSources;
    }

    [Description("Returns a list of endpoints")]
    [HttpGet("endpoints")]
    public ActionResult Endpoints()
    {
        var actions = _endpointDataSources.SelectMany(it => it.Endpoints)
            .OfType<RouteEndpoint>()
            .Where(
                it => it.Metadata
                    .OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()
                    .Any()
            )
            .Select(
                e => {
                    var actionDescriptor = e.Metadata
                        .OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()
                        .First();

                    var isControllerIgnored = actionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.GetCustomAttribute<ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute>()?.IgnoreApi ?? false;
                    var isActionIgnored = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo                       .GetCustomAttribute<ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute>()?.IgnoreApi ?? false;

                    return new
                    {
                        ControllerName = actionDescriptor.ControllerName,
                        ControllerType = actionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.FullName,
                        ActionDescription = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description,
                        ControllerDescription = actionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo
                            .GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()
                            ?.Description,
                        Method = actionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.OfType<HttpMethodMetadata>()
                            .FirstOrDefault()
                            ?.HttpMethods?[0],
                        Path = $"/{e.RoutePattern!.RawText!.TrimStart('/')}",
                    };
                }
            )
            .ToList();

        return Ok(actions);
    }
}
```

when you visit `/info/endpoints`, you'll get a list of endpoints:

```json
[
  {
    "controllerName": "Things",
    "controllerType": "ApiPlayground.ThingsController",
    "actionDescription": "Returns a list of endpoints",
    "controllerDescription": "Provides info",
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/info/endpoints"
  }
]
```

Comment: does this code give the description of the controller or the action where it is defined? `  [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` should work right?

Comment: Check the output, it gives both descriptions

Comment: I wanted to group by ControllerName

Comment: Then group it? It's a C# exercise after this point

Comment: _[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` should work right?_ You need to filter by that attribute yourself. See my edit for `isControllerIgnored`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to abdusco answer

We can create a helper class to get application all areas, controllers and actions along with controller and action description.

#asp.net-core-8 #asp.net-mvc-core-8

Model class to return data

```
public class ApplicationRoutes
{
    public string? AreaName { get; set; }
    public string? ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string? ControllerDescription { get; set; }
    public string? ControllerType { get; set; }
    public string? ActionName { get; set; }
    public string? ActionDescription { get; set; }
    public string? HttpMethod { get; set; }
    public string? Path { get; set; }
}
```

Interface for helper class

```
public interface IApplicationRouteHelper
{
     public IEnumerable<ApplicationRoutes> GetAllRoutes();
}
```

Helper Class code

```
public class ApplicationRouteHelper : IApplicationRouteHelper
{
    private IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> _endpointDataSources;

    public ApplicationRouteHelper(IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpointDataSources)
    {
        _endpointDataSources = endpointDataSources;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationRoutes> GetAllRoutes()
    {
        var actions = _endpointDataSources.SelectMany(it => it.Endpoints)
            .OfType<RouteEndpoint>()
            .Where(
                it => it.Metadata.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>().Any()
            ).Select(
                e =>
                {
                    var actionDescriptor = e.Metadata.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>().First();
                    var isControllerIgnored = actionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.GetCustomAttribute<ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute>()?.IgnoreApi ?? false;
                    var isActionIgnored = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute>()?.IgnoreApi ?? false;

                    return new ApplicationRoutes()
                    {
                        AreaName = actionDescriptor?.ControllerTypeInfo?.GetCustomAttribute<AreaAttribute>()?.RouteValue,
                        ControllerName = actionDescriptor?.ControllerName,
                        ControllerType = actionDescriptor?.ControllerTypeInfo?.FullName,
                        ControllerDescription = actionDescriptor?.ControllerTypeInfo?.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description,
                        ActionName = actionDescriptor?.ActionName,
                        ActionDescription = actionDescriptor?.MethodInfo?.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description,
                        HttpMethod = actionDescriptor?.EndpointMetadata?.OfType<HttpMethodMetadata>()?.FirstOrDefault()?.HttpMethods?[0],
                        Path = $"/{e.RoutePattern!.RawText!.TrimStart('/')}",
                    };
                }
            ).ToList();

        return actions;
    }
```

Add Application Routes Helper Service refrence in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IApplicationRouteHelper, ApplicationRouteHelper>();
```

Now we can access all routes any where in our project by calling helper method.

I call it inside Home controller

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IApplicationRouteHelper _appRoutes;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IApplicationRouteHelper appRoutes)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _appRoutes = appRoutes;
    }

    [Description("Application all routes")]
    public IActionResult GetAllRoutes()
    {

        var routes = _appRoutes.GetAllRoutes();

        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

Result

```
  [{
    "AreaName" : "Common"
    "controllerName": "Home",
    "ControllerDescription" : "{""ModuleCode"":""Common"",""Developed By"":""Pardeep Bhardwaj""}"
    "controllerType": "YYAN.Web.Areas.Common.Controllers.HomeController",
    "ActionName" : "GetAllRoutes"
    "ActionDescription": "Application all routes",
    "HttpMethod": "GET",
    "path": ""
  }]
```

Please upvote answer if you found helpful!