# Determine health check routes at runtime in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, health-check, asp.net-core-routing

I added health checks to my ASP.NET Core 6 app, and everything is working properly.

I need to determine (programmatically, at runtime) all the health check routes, e.g. `/healthz`, etc.

I tried:

```cs
// inject IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource>
// ...
var routes = _endpointDataSources.SelectMany(source => source.Endpoints);
```

But there's no way I can select the correct endpoints (using linq) without using a hack or magic string. The healthcheck endpoints have [`"Heath checks"`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0602a3266ea9d116df479d558cd99e854d4bc03d/src/Middleware/HealthChecks/src/Builder/HealthCheckEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs#L18) as their display names, but I assume that can change at any time, so *it's not reliable*.

How can I get those endpoints in a reliable way that won't break on the next update?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435734/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-routes-in-asp-net-core.  shows how to iterate all your endpoints.

Comment: @bmiller Thanks! I tried something similar (updated the question accordingly), but it's not a reliable way as the healthcheck endpoints have no property I can use to select them in a linq query (without using magic strings).

Comment: can you add the part where are you adding healthcheck to your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Health checks are (currently) [implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0602a3266ea9d116df479d558cd99e854d4bc03d/src/Middleware/HealthChecks/src/Builder/HealthCheckEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs#L65) by creating a middleware pipeline and mapping the resulting delegate, with a display name `"Health checks"`.

```cs
var pipeline = endpoints.CreateApplicationBuilder()
    .UseMiddleware<HealthCheckMiddleware>(args)
    .Build();

return endpoints.Map(pattern, pipeline)
    .WithDisplayName(DefaultDisplayName);
```

As you have discovered, you should be able to discover all endpoints, search for any health checks, and list their path via;

```cs
var sources = provider.GetService<IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource>>(); // via DI

var routes = sources
    .SelectMany(s => s.Endpoints)
    .OfType<RouteEndpoint>()
    .Where(e => e.DisplayName == "Health checks")
    .Select(e => e.RoutePattern)
    .ToList();
```

So to answer your actual question, while the method you would use to configure endpoint routes is unlikely to change. There are mentions in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#aspnet-core-endpoint-definition) demonstrating how endpoint routing meta data can be examined. But I wouldn't expect any strong guarantee of future support.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the magic string is [set here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0602a3266ea9d116df479d558cd99e854d4bc03d/src/Middleware/HealthChecks/src/Builder/HealthCheckEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs#L18). I don't know how reliable it is, but looks like there's no other way.

Comment: I would add this: `.Where(x => e.RequestDelegate?.Target is HealthCheckMiddleware || e.DisplayName == "Health checks")`. Seems safer than relying on that string alone.

Comment: Checking just the target is probably better. Assuming that part of pipeline request delegates always works that way....

Comment: True, even that could change! The issue with these sort of problems is the plumbing is hidden once the app is built. Not much is exposed at that point.